# Let X represent the difference between the number of heads and the number of tails when a coin is tossed 32 times. Then P(X=12)

Tags: probability, statistics

Let X represent the difference between the number of heads and the number of tails when a coin is tossed 32 times. Then P(X=12)

**Work :**

Let H be the number of Heads & T be the number of Tails.

We want P(|H-T| = 12)

We have T = 32-H   so,

P (|H-T| = 12 )  = P ( |H-32+H | = 12 )

= P ( |2H-32 | = 12 )

= P (2H-32 = 12  or  2H-32 = -12)

=P (H = 22 or H = 10)

= (32 C 22 )*(0.5)^32     + (32 C 10 )*(0.5)^32

= 0.0300

Am I doing correct or wrong?

Thank you in advance..

Comment: Yes, you are doing correct.

Comment: @Kenny Lau , can you please recheck it, any decimal answer number changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(32%20choose%2022)2%5E(-31)) agrees with you to the places you gave.  Note that ${32 \choose 22}={32 \choose 10}$ so I did just one and removed one factor of $\frac 12$

Comment: yes (32 C 22 ) same as ( 32 C 10). Thanks for confirmed... I am doing correct.. Thank you...!!